# TypeError: function(...).then is not a function

Tags: angularjs

Al tratar de obtener la información almacenada en el ***localstorage*** por medio de un factory inyectándolo en el controller, se produce el siguiente error.

> TypeError: obtenerGruposProf.datosGrupos(...).then is not a function

El código es el siguiente:

```
angular.module('gruposProfesor', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
    .controller('mostrarGruposProf', mostrarGruposProf)
    .factory('obtenerGruposProf', obtenerGruposProf);


mostrarGruposProf.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerGruposProf'];

function mostrarGruposProf($scope, obtenerGruposProf) {

    obtenerGruposProf.datosGrupos().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

}

function obtenerGruposProf() {   

   return {

    datosGrupos: function() {

        var getGrupos, infoGrupos;

        getGrupos = localStorage.getItem('GruposProf');
        infoGrupos = JSON.parse(getGrupos);

        return infoGrupos;

    }

  };

}
```

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Parece que el resultado de `datosGrupos` no tiene un método `then`.

Comment: Pues @LuiggiMendoza, `obtenerHorarioProf.datosHorario().then(function(informacion) {});`
Este es otro factory para llamar el horario del profesor,  la verdad es igual por decirlo asi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si estás usando un método `.then` lo más probable es que el objeto que lo antecede es un [thenable](https://promisesaplus.com/)(o un objeto que tiene un [método then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)). Usualmente quien implementa este tipo de método son las [Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa). Mirando tu código más de cerca tenemos

```
datosGrupos: function() {

    var getGrupos, infoGrupos;

    getGrupos = localStorage.getItem('GruposProf');
    infoGrupos = JSON.parse(getGrupos);

    return infoGrupos;

}
```

al que luego llamas

```
obtenerGruposProf.datosGrupos().then(//....
```

El error ocurre porque la función `datosGrupos` no devuelve una promesa y por lo tanto no hay un método `.then`. Lo que devuelve esa función como tal es el dato que tienes en el localStorage, un objeto común y corriente.

Para que te devuelva una promesa debes hacer algo como

```
angular.module('gruposProfesor', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
    .factory('obtenerGruposProf', obtenerGruposProf);

obtenerGruposProf.$inject = ['$q'];

function obtenerGruposProf($q) {       
   return {    
    datosGrupos: function() {
        var defer = $q.defer(); 
        // creas un objeto Deferred que tiene un método resolve y reject   
        var getGrupos, infoGrupos;    
        getGrupos = localStorage.getItem('GruposProf');
        infoGrupos = JSON.parse(getGrupos);  
        // resuelves la promesa con el valor obtenido
        defer.resolve(infoGrupos) ;
        // devuelves el .promise que es el que tiene el método then 
        return defer.promise;    
    }    
  };    
}
```

Básicamente estarías devolviendo una promesa con el **resultado futuro** ya resuelto. Esto es un error por dos razones

1. Estás creando asincronía en una operación que es inevitablemente sincrónica.

   Las operaciones en localStorage son sincrónicas. El método [getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) devuelve inmediatamente un string, o sea el resultado de la operación, no un resultado futuro.

   Es mucho más simple escribir

   ```
   var data = obtenerGruposProf.datosGrupos();
   console.log(data);
   ```

   que escribir

   ```
   obtenerGruposProf.datosGrupos().then(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   });
   ```

   ya que estás creando anidamiento innecesario. Esto te pone un paso mas cerca del [callback-hell](http://callbackhell.com/) el cual es una de las razones por las que existen las promesas.
2. Usualmente escribir las promesas de esa forma es considerado un [antipatrón](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) ya que

   > Las promesas sirven para hacer que el código asíncronico retenga la mayor parte de las propiedades perdidas del código sincrónico tales como indentación plana y un sólo canal para los errores.

   Como viste anteriormente no necesitas crear indentación y en caso de error puedes usar un simple [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch)

   > En el antipatrón Deferred, los objetos "deferred" son creados sin motivo, complicando el código.

Hay un caso en el que **sí** te conviene escribir el código de esta forma y es cuando, por ejemplo, tienes que hacer una llamada ajax o devolver un resultado almacenado ya. Básicamente tienes dos opciones, una es sincrónica y la otra asincrónica. En este caso puedes hacer esto.

```
angular.module('gruposProfesor', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
    .factory('obtenerGruposProf', obtenerGruposProf);

obtenerGruposProf.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];

function obtenerGruposProf($q, $http) {       
   return {    
    datosGrupos: function() {
        var getGrupos, infoGrupos;    
        getGrupos = localStorage.getItem('GruposProf');
        if (getGrupos) {
            infoGrupos = JSON.parse(getGrupos);
            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.resolve(infoGrupos);
            return defer.promise;
        } else {
            return $http.get('/miapi/gruposprof');    
        }    
    }    
  };    
}
```

Luego manipulas tus datos usando

```
obtenerGruposProf.datosGrupos().then(function(data) {
    localStorage.setItem('GruposProf', JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data);
});
```

En este caso el deferred si es necesario ya que no puedes saber con seguridad si la llamada será asincrónica o no y el uso del `.then` está plenamente justificado.

Por último ten en cuenta que si lo que quieres es cachear el resultado de tus llamadas ajax en el localStorage ya existe un servicio para hacer eso.

Échale un vistazo a https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache.

Comment: Gracias, @devconcept, ahora si esta totalmente claro, y es de mucha ayuda la respuesta.